# Email Error_Message() in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, error-handling

I have a stored procedure that loops through a recordset and attaches files to an email which is then sent to a user.

The procedure can fail for various reasons. When it does

```
IF @returncode > 0
```

I generate an error mail to myself.

I would like to get the full text from the

```
error_message()
```

procedure and push it into the text body also.

I have tried enclosing my code in a Try block and putting the email send code in the catch block.

I have also tried excluding the email send code from the catch block and simply assigning the error_message() result to a variable which I can reference in the mail

Both do not work :(

Comment: Does your procedure throw an exception when it fails or does it just return a non-zero return code?

Answer (score 2):

To send error_message() in an email you need to cast it to a varchar.  Example below should work for you after updating the email addresses and mail profile used:

```
    Declare @IsError int = 0
    Declare @ErrorMessage VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    BEGIN TRY
             -- Send email 
             EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = 'Someone@abc.com'
                                        , @from_Address = 'sqlemail.abc.com'
                                        , @body = 'Email Body'
                                        , @subject = 'Email Subject'
                                        , @body_format = 'HTML'
                                        , @profile_name = 'DBProfileName'
              SET @IsError = @@ERROR
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
            -- Store exception information casting error message to varchar
            SELECT @IsError = 1, @ErrorMessage = 'Exception message: ' + Cast (Error_Message() as varchar)  + ';'
    END CATCH

    IF @IsError <> 0
    BEGIN
         DECLARE @Subject VARCHAR(250)
         SELECT @Subject = 'Server Name: ' + @@SERVERNAME + '; Database Name: ' +  DB_NAME() + ';' + ' - Email failed'
         EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = 'AlertSupport@abc.com'
                                    , @from_Address = 'sqlemail.abc.com'
                                    , @body = @ErrorMessage
                                    , @subject = @Subject
                                    , @profile_name = 'DBProfileName'

        Raiserror('Error encountered while sending email', 16, 1);

    END
```